# Lifetime of temporary object: iterator to temporary vector in nested function call

Tags: c++, iterator, lifetime, function-call, temporary-objects

Let's suppose that I have such classes:

```
struct QString {
    //return null terminated array
    std::vector<char> toLocal8Bit() const;
};

struct string_view {
    const char *data;
    size_t len;
    string_view(const char *str): data(str), len(std::strlen(str)) {}
};
```

and I have function with such signature:

```
void f(const string_view& str);
```

Is it valid code

```
QString str;
f(string_view(&*str.toLocal8Bit().begin()));
```

?

I mean when temporary std::vector will be destroyed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temporary is destroyed at the end of the full statement. So this is safe.

Comment: But here actually two nested temporary, they will be destroyed in reverse order?

Comment: It doesn't matter here. It only matters that the first temporary still exists when the second is constructed.